# Объявление объекта класса наследника

Tags: java, классы, объекты

В кратце. Например у нас есть **суперкласс** "Cat", и его **наследник** "smallCat". **object** это название объекта

Чтоб объявить объект класса **наследника smallCat** мы обычно пишем: **smallCat object = new SmallCat();**

Но есть такая вариация объявления объекта которую я не могу понять: **Cat object = new SmallCat();**

Можете пожалуйста объяснить вторую вариацию и чем она **отличается** от первой вариаций.

Буду благодарен!

Comment: Есть тип переменной, а есть её значение. Это как адрес дома и сам дом. Вот тут `Cat object = new SmallCat();` вы создаете переменную типа `Cat`, но пишете в значение переменной экземпляр `SmallCat`.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование из подкласса в суперкласс называется upcasting оно как правило выполняется неявно. Есть и downcasting преобразование из суперкласса в подкласс.
Подробнее почитайте [тут](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java-type-casting)

По второму вопросу, разница. По сути это переменные содержащие в себе ссылку на объект SmallCat. Только в первом случае это ссылка типа SmallCat а во втором Cat. Если представить class неким лекалом над адресном пространством. То наведя лекало Cat на область созданную конструктором SmallCat мы увидим кошку(Cat) так как он его суперкласс.

Comment: 20 лет пишу код, впервые вижу этот термин русскими буквами :)

Comment: Артем как есть написал. Не важно как лижбы смысл не менялся

Comment: да я чего, я ничего, просто удивился )

Comment: Исправил не буду людей смущять

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант представляет собой пример полиморфизма в Java.

У Вас есть кот и маленький кот. Маленький кот - это всё еще кот, ему присущи свойства кота. **Если Вы пишете какой-то метод, который работает с котами - без разницы какими - Вы можете указать кота как входящий параметр.**

Т.к. как код Вашего метода работает только с видимыми полями и методами, то с маленькими котами он тоже будет работать, **потому что маленькие коты наследуют свойства котов**.

В итоге, Вы можете обращаться к любым подвидам котов, используя ссылку на класс-родитель (это удобно в случаях, которые я описал выше). Ограничение состоит в том, что **Вы не сможете через такую ссылку получить доступ к методам и полям специфичным именно для маленьких котов**. Если такая необходимость всё же встанет, придется проверять объект на соотв-ие конкретному классу и приводить его явно.